# Taking post parameters in ajax comment form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to customize one comment form from template which I purchased. In short I have 3 files - `post.php`, `comment_post.php` and `main.js`. In `post.php` is simple html comment form. I'm not that good in `ajax` part and still trying to learn php so I'll need some help with this.

```
<form class="row" role="form" id="comments-form" name="comments-form" action="comments-send.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-name-error" name="comments[form-name]" id="form-name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="email" class="form-control form-email-error" id="form-email" name="comments[form-email]" placeholder="Email">                          
        <input type="hidden" name="comments[post_id]" value="<?php echo $row['post_id'];?>" >
        <textarea class="form-control input-row-2 form-review-error" rows="3" id="form-comments" name="comments[form-review]" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
        <div class="form-group text-right btn-submit">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark button-submit">Send</button>
            <div class="message-success alert-success alert hidden" style="position: absolute"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
         </div> 
</form>
```

I have one hidden field to get post_id..
Here is `comment_post.php` which is the problem ( I think ). The errors are `Undefined variable: comment_author_name, comment_author_image .. etc`

```
if(isset($_POST['comments'])) {

$response = array('status' => '', 'errors'=>array());

foreach($_POST['comments'] as $key => $value) {
    if($value == '') {
        $response['errors'][$key.'-error'] = 'error'; 
    }
}
if(empty($response['errors'])) {

    $_POST['comments']['form-name'] = $comment_author_name;
    $_POST['comments']['form-email'] = $comment_author_email;
    $_POST['comments']['post_id'] = $post_id;
    $_POST['comments']['form-review'] = $comment_text;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (comment_author_name, comment_author_email, comment_date, comment_text, post_id) 
            VALUES (:comment_author_name, :comment_author_email, NOW(), :comment_text, :post_id)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindValue(":comment_author_name", $comment_author_name);
        $stmt->bindValue(":comment_author_email", $comment_author_email);
        $stmt->bindValue(":post_id", $post_id);  
        $stmt->bindValue(":comment_text", $comment_text);

    $stmt->execute();       


    $response['status'] = 'ok';
} else {
    $response['status'] = 'error';
}
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

In original file (`comment_post.php`) there is nothing for database insertion and this is my code. I'm not sure how to get values from the form when is send to the php part. This is from `main.js` file for the `comment_form`.

```
$("#comments-form").submit(function(e) {
$('#comments-form .form-control').removeClass('#comments-form message-error');
$.post("comments-send.php", $('#comments-form').serialize(), function(data) {
    if (data.status === 'ok') {
        $("#comments-form .message-success").removeClass('hidden').velocity({ opacity : 1 });
        $("#comments-form .button-submit").addClass('button-transparent');
        $('#comments-form .form-control').val('');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#comments-form .message-success").velocity({ opacity : 0 }, function() {
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
            });
            $("#comments-form .button-submit").removeClass('button-transparent');
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        $.each(data.errors, function(i, e) {
            $('.' + i).addClass('#comments-form message-error');
        });
    }
}, 'json');
   e.preventDefault();
});

$("#comments-form").on('keyup', '.contact-form', function() {
    var that = this;
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
        $(this).removeClass('message-error');
    } else {
        $(that).addClass('message-error');
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not setting your variables correctly

update to this

```
$comment_author_name = $_POST['comments']['form-name'];
$comment_author_email = $_POST['comments']['form-email'];
$post_id = $_POST['comments']['post_id'];
$comment_text = $_POST['comments']['form-review'];
```

What you want to do is actually get the values from the $_POST and save them to the variables you have created.

Previously you were doing the oposite, therefore the variables did not exist and you were also reseting the values in your $_POST

Comment: Well... that was the problem but what is the difference between `$_POST['comments']['form-name'] = $comment_author_name;` and `$comment_author_name = $_POST['comments']['form-name'];`

Comment: Thank's very much. I really didn't know that both there is differences between both ways.

Comment: $_POST['comments']['form-name'] = $comment_author_name; sets the value of $comment_author_name to $_POST['comments']['form-name']. Whereas $comment_author_name = $_POST['comments']['form-name'] sets the value of  $_POST['comments']['form-name'] to the variable $comment_author_name.

Comment: nice :) Glad i could help